# TableView is showing blank cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

OK, so my app worked fine and after a while and the cells don't work anymore.

1. The tableView is connected to DataSource and Delegate
2. The console is printing all the values inside the Array
3. When the app is run, it shows 3 cells, but no information inside

   ```
   var names = ["Bob", "Bill", "Billy"]

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NamesCell

        cell.name.text = self.names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
   }
   ```

   NamesCell (custom Cell)

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
   ```

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of what you are getting?, also put the line cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: what is NamesCell in your code? Is that a custom class you have created?

Comment: check height of name label, it might be zero. Set row height in storyboard if missing.

Comment: also share your `NamesCell` details

Comment: Ok, so checked the height and it is set as 65, I added a Red background color to the cell and here is what I get https://i.imgsafe.org/ef0651bd27.png

Comment: make sure you have added the name label outlet in NamesCell class

Comment: I added the NamesCell class code in the question

Comment: replace: cell.name.text = self.names[indexPath.row] as! String

Comment: btw, i just added another random label in the cell and that label isn't popping up either

Comment: @SuhasPatil I did what you said and it still won't work

Comment: Have you linked the custom cell in Storyboard? We may forget it sometimes.

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M yes I have

Comment: Do you guys think It might be a bug, i've looked everywhere in the code, even put breakpoints inside the cellforrowatindexpath and it runs perfectly but doesn't appear on the screen

Comment: No, it should appear, Can you show your storyboard screenshot with selecting NamesCell

Comment: @user54272 have you reload the table? and can you add background color to the name label and post the screen shot here?

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/ef4ba93fd2.png

Comment: i have not seen the cell identifier "cell" . Have you added that?

Comment: I reloaded the table and when I add a background color to the label I get: https://i.imgsafe.org/ef57147632.png

Comment: @SuhasPatil yes I did add the cell identifier

Comment: I fixed it by removing the constraints and re-adding them back. weird?

Comment: Strange...!!! Good job

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I cleared the constraints and re-added the same constraints back onto the cell label and it worked. Very Weird?

Answer (score 0):

Remove constraints and add them again , it's a problem of constraints. your code is ok .